# Get Sorted data in ascending order according to price from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

```
"SELECT * FROM " + PRO_TABLE + " WHERE "
                + PRO_CATID + "= '" + cat_id + "' " +" AND "+ PRO_CAT + "= '" + cat_name + "' " + " AND "
                + PRO_SUB_CATID + "= '" + subcat_id + "' ORDER BY "+ PRO_PP + " ASC ";
```

Comment: what problem are you facing ?

Comment: when ever i rum a query data is not coming in sorted order

Comment: 15.0
 20.0
 10.0
20.0
 20.0
 20.0
20.0
0.0
 20.0
 0.0
 12.99
12.99
12.99
 12.99
 12.99
12.99
12.99
10.05
 12.99
 0.0
 6.99
6.99
 6.99
 6.99
6.99
6.99
 6.99
 6.99
 6.99
 6.99

Comment: there are the price of product but on the query  is not working

Comment: 6.99
6.99
6.99
6.99
6.99
6.99
6.99
6.99
6.99
6.99
20
20
20
20
20
20
15
12.99
12.99
12.99
12.99
12.99
12.99
12.99
12.99
10.05
10
0
0
0
 getting output in this format

Comment: Update the question with the data you are getting and what you are expecting.

Comment: What is the datatype of `PRO_PP` field?

Comment: it is of string type

Comment: @RasikaSingh check my answer

Comment: Sorting a string type sorts the data in alphabetic order. To sort it as according to value you should use a number type field or use `cast` as @IntelliJAmiya's answer shows.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **CAST**.

```
ORDER BY CAST(PRO_PP AS REAL) ASC
```

Comment: getting syntax error --  "SELECT * FROM " + PRO_TABLE + " WHERE "
                + PRO_CATID + "= '" + cat_id + "' " +" AND "
                + PRO_SUB_CATID + "= '" + subcat_id + "' ORDER BY CAST " + PRO_PP + " ASC ";

Comment: can you please help me to solve this issue....

Comment: String query = "SELECT * FROM " + PRO_TABLE + " WHERE "
                + PRO_CATID + "= '" + cat_id + "' " +" AND "
                + PRO_SUB_CATID + "= '" + subcat_id + "' ORDER BY CAST " +(PRO_PP + " AS REAL ") + " ASC ";

Comment: i have added this code...

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "prices": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM pro_table WHERE category_ids= '118'  AND sub_category_ids= '0' ORDER BY CAST prices ASC

Comment: String query = "SELECT * FROM " + PRO_TABLE + " WHERE "
                + PRO_CATID + "= '" + cat_id + "' " +" AND "
                + PRO_SUB_CATID + "= '" + subcat_id + "' ORDER BY CAST " +(PRO_PP + " AS DOUBLE ") + " DESC ";

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: i want data for both asc and desc order

Comment: getting syntax error in above query

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: near "prices": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM pro_table WHERE category_ids= '118'  AND sub_category_ids= '0' ORDER BY CAST prices AS DOUBLE  ASC

Comment: near "prices": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM pro_table WHERE category_ids= '118'  AND sub_category_ids= '0' ORDER BY CAST prices AS DOUBLE  DESC

Comment: @RasikaSingh `"' ORDER BY CAST(" + PRO_PP + " AS DOUBLE) DESC ";`